# Oracle SQL: Is there any way to list all entries where IP version is IPv6?

Tags: sql, oracle, ipv6

In a table, we have multiple rows which records IP Address of login. These days we are getting logins from IPv6 address as well.

I am trying to find a way to list all rows where we have IPv6 entries.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, Its more generic question, that's why not provided sample data and all I need is the regex that you have mentioned in your answer.

Comment: Would be sooo easy with Postgres ;) `where family(ip_address) = 6`

Comment: Guys, giving a negative is so easy, just add why you are doing that ? All I asked How to find IPv6 if it is there in my table. And why you need sample data for that ?  Table name could be anything and column name could be anything. You can write an example and I can understand from that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, you could do something like this:

```
select t.*
from t
where not regexp_like(ip, '[0-9]{1-3}.[0-9]{1-3}.[0-9]{1-3}.[0-9]{1-3}')
```

Or more simply:

```
select t.*
from t
where ip like '%:%'  -- ipv6 contains colons
```

Answer (score 0):

as  IPv6 addresses have a size of 128 bits with 4 digits after every colon we can have like this:

```
create table ns_tab3 (val varchar(100));
insert into ns_tab3 values('2002:2002:2002:2002:2002:2002:2002:2002'); 
insert into ns_tab3 values('2002:2432:2432:2543:2974:2002:2002:2002'); 
insert into ns_tab3 values('2002:2002:2002:2002:2002:2002:2002:2432'); 
insert into ns_tab3 values('2002:2002:2002:2002:2002:2002:2002:1920'); 
insert into ns_tab3 values('2002:2002:2002:2002:2002:2002:2002:0201'); 
select * from ns_tab3;

select * from ns_tab3 where regexp_like(val,'[0-9]{4}:[0-9]{4}:[0-9]{4}:[0-9]{4}:[0- 
9]{4}:[0-9]{4}:[0-9]{4}:[0-9]{4}');
```